# Minimizing and maximizing a term by placement of parantheses

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

So, if we have an expression of the form $b_1 * b_2 * b_3 * \ldots * b_n$
where $*$ is defined to be multiplication OR division and $b_1, \ldots, b_n$ are positive integers

What would be a placement of parentheses that would minimize the expression $b_1*b_2*b_3*\ldots*b_n$.

****And what about a placement of parenthesis that would maximize the expression?***

Comment: Your question is not quite clear: What does "can be multiplication OR division" mean here? Can any single * be one of the both, or are all the * occuring in the term always the same? In other words, could $a * b * c$ be $(a \cdot b) / c$?

Comment: In the latter case, note that parenthesis placement makes no difference if $*$ is multiplication (why?).

Comment: So, * can be defined as multiplication or divission of the integers above.

Comment: When it says or, I am thinking it is in the context of an inclusive or so it could be either multiplication or division

Comment: If I understand you correctly, $a_1 * \cdots * a_n$ has two possible interpretations: $a_1 \cdots a_n$ (* is multiplication), and $a_1 / \ldots / a_n$ (* is division, with parentheses yet to be places). What have you tried so far, and how did this problem come up?

Comment: I thought of utilizing recursion and induction but dont see the direct relevance. I came across this problem in preparation for the Putnam

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37092/discussion-between-johannes-kloos-and-mary).

Comment: The algorithmics which is behind all this is a branch of Operational Research called "Dynamic Programming" ; see the example "Matrix chain multiplication" at the end of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming

Comment: Would you be able to add some stuff here? I read through it but was a little confused

Comment: The minimum is $b_1 / (b_2 * ( b_3 * \cdots ( b_{n-1} * b_n )\cdots)) = (\ldots ((b_1 /b_2) /b_3 ) \cdots / b_n )$.

Comment: Why is that and could you please provide a justification?

Comment: You didn't clarify the question about the meaning of * OR /. Without this input, we can't answer.

Answer (score 2):

For any $m \ge 2$, let $\mathcal{S}_m$ be the statement:

> For all $(c_1,c_2, \ldots, c_m ) \in \mathbb{Z}_+^m$, independent how one introduce brackets and assign $\times$ or $/$ to the slots marked by $*$, expression of the form $c_1 * c_2 * \cdots * c_m$
>   always takes values in the set $\bigg\{ c_1 \prod_{k=2}^m c_k^{e_k} : e_k \in \{ -1, +1 \} \bigg\}$.

$\mathcal{S}_2$ is trivially true.

For $m > 2$, assume $S_k$ is true for all $2 \le k < m$.
For any $(c_1,c_2, \ldots, c_m ) \in \mathbb{Z}_+^m$ and ways of introduce brackets, the expression $c_1 * c_2 * \cdots * c_m$ can takes following six forms:

1. $c_1 \times (c_2 * \cdots * c_m )$
2. $c_1 / (c_2 * \cdots * c_m )$
3. $(c_1 * \cdots * c_{m-1} ) \times c_m$
4. $(c_1 * \cdots * c_{m-1} ) / c_m$
5. $(c_1 * \cdots * c_{p}) \times (c_{p+1} * \cdots * c_m)$ for some $2 \le p < m-1$.
6. $(c_1 * \cdots * c_{p}) / (c_{p+1} * \cdots * c_m)$ for some $2 \le p < m-1$.

It is easy to see

- For the first four cases, $\mathcal{S}_m$ is true by $\mathcal{S}_{m-1}$.
- For the fifth and sixth cases, $\mathcal{S}_m$ is true by $\mathcal{S}_p$ and $\mathcal{S}_{m-p}$.

This means $$\mathcal{S}_2 \land \ldots \land \mathcal{S}_{m-1}\quad \implies \quad\mathcal{S}_m$$
By principle of induction, $\mathcal{S}_m$ is true for all $m \ge 2$.

In any expression of the form
$c_1 \prod_{k=2}^m c_k^{e_k}$ where $e_k \in \{ -1, +1 \}$,

- If we change any $e_k$ from $1$ to $-1$, the value will not increase.
- If we change any $e_k$ from $-1$ to $1$, the value will not decrease.

This implies

$$\prod_{k=1}^m c_k = c_1 \prod_{k=1}^m c_k^{+1} \ge c_1 \prod_{k=2}^m c_k^{e_k} \ge c_1 \prod_{k=2}^m c_k^{-1} = \frac{c_1}{\prod_{k=2}^m c_k}$$

Notice the values on LHS/RHS can be achieved by pure multiplication/division evaluated in canonical order. The maximal/minimal values of the expression
$c_1 * \cdots * c_m$ are
$$
\begin{align}
\verb/maximum/ &= ((\cdots(c_1 \times c_2) \times c_3 )\times\ldots \times c_m )\\
\verb/minimum/ &= ((\cdots((c_1/c_2)/c_3)\ldots /c_m )
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Since the $b_n$ are positive integers:

To maximize: $b_1*b_2*b_3*...*b_n$ with any parentheses you like, because of commutativity of multiplication.

To minimize: $((...((b_1/b_2)/b_3)/...)/b_n)$ (which is also the standard interpretation if you leave the parentheses out).